# write a shell script to add job to cron

Tags: shell

I write a shell script below to add a job to cron.

```
#!/bin/sh
touch date.cron
echo '*/3 * * * * /usr/sbin/ntpdate 192.168.2.3' >date.cron
crontab date.cron
rm date.cron
```

But I don't want to create the file date.cron. How can I add the job directly without creating the file. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
( crontab -l 2>/dev/null | grep -Fv ntpdate ; printf -- "*/3 * * * * /usr/sbin/ntpdate 192.168.2.3" ) | crontab
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Benoit Thiery

Comment: To avoid impacting other lines in the crontab. Only ntpdate line will be added/replaced thanks to grep.

Answer (score 1):

Use >> "append" instead of > "output"

```
#!/bin/bash
Task="'*/3 * * * * /usr/sbin/ntpdate 192.168.2.3'";
$Task >> date.cron;
```

Greetings.